# No 404 page available

Tags: 404-error

There is 404.php in the theme uploaded. But when there is search for non-existent page.
The 404.php does not show up. What is the reason?

Assistance required.

Comment: I got it and updated my site. if somebody was going to comment. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "search for non-existent page"?

Comment: I meant searching a page, which is not present in my domain/website

Comment: You still are saying the same. Searching a page, where? In the standar seacrh form? Searching a page title? Searching a term that return zero results? Using a URL for a page that doesn't exist? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

> *There is 404.php in the theme uploaded. But when there is search for non-existent page. The 404.php does not show up.*

*When there is search for non-existent page* doesn't produce the 404 page, but simply shows the `search.php`'s else portion. A simple `search.php` is like:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while( have_posts() : the_post(); ?>
      <div><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
   <?php endwhile;
<?php else : ?>
   <div><?php _e( "No results found", "text-domain" ); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

A search for non-existent pages will show the `else` part only.

A 404 will generate when something is browsed through URL and that doesn't exist at all. So at that time the `404.php` will be echoed.

If you want to show the else part a more stylish like 404, design the else part as per your demand. :) And if you want the user to redirect to the 404 page (I don't know why someone can want this!), you can also that like the following (in `search.php`):

```
<?php else : ?>
   <?php
   wp_redirect( home_url('/kauwa') ); //kauwa - garbage text that won't produce a real page
   exit;
   ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But as I said, it's not a good practice, you know.

Comment: Thank you for that Mayeenul Islam. I would implement that.